# Keyboard shortcut for testing procedure in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm using pl/sql developer for writing stored procedures in Oracle. When writing a stored procedure or function i need to test it. For testing i have to right click on the procedure name and click test from the popup menu.

Is there any keyboard shortcut or other convenient way to test it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no key combination assigned by default. So you need to do the following:

1. Go to `Tools\Preferences` choose `Key configuration` in the `User interface` section
2. In the appeared list find `Name` called `File/New/Test Window` and press any key combination you want to use to open a test window.